# Hydrostatic force acting on a hemispherical impression

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering

Consider vertical wall which contains a hemispherical impression as shown. Water is filled only upto the centre of hemispherical impression, i.e. to a depth of L. It is required to know the horizontal force acting on the hemispherical impression, which is in contact with water.

[image: ni]

For doing this, I take a fluid element around the impression which is basically a cuboid inside which there is a 1/4 sphere impression.

[image]

In my understanding, the horizontal force should be equal to the force on the front vertical face of this "cuboid", since the "cuboidal" fluid element has to be in equilibrium.

So to determine that force I take at a depth h, an elemental area dA= dh. 2r. The force acting on this element will be

$$\delta F= (P_{atm} + \rho gh).2r dh$$

The total force on the front vertical area of the "cuboid" will be,

$$F= \int_{L-r}^{L}(P_{atm} + \rho gh).2r dh$$

I have been using this method to solve some problems but I'm not getting correct answers. Which makes me think something is wrong with this method.

**What exactly is wrong in this method?**

Comment: You cannot use full front vertical face, but just the semicircle part. The rest of the face is in equilibrium with opposite vertical face outside of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

First of we need to take to atmosphere pressure out of the integral.
For example, using your case of 1/4 sphere. with its base at depth 0 and vertical axis H. and depth of L.

If we consider a horizontal thin cut of the surface its surface equation will be. assuming the center of the circle at the origin.
$$(x-0)^2 + (H-0)^2=R^2, \quad x^2 + H^2= R^2, x_0=R$$

$$x^2= R^2-H^2 \rightarrow dA= x*dH=\sqrt {R^2-H^2}dH $$

$$F=P_{atm}+\rho(L-H) \sqrt {R^2-H^2}dH*$$
This is the deferential pressure. total pressure Ft is

$$F_t=P_{atm}+\rho\int_{0}^{H}(L-H) \sqrt {R^2-H^2}dH$$

Comment: Kamran, I'm not clear with what vertical axis H means